# JSON as String in Spring Integration

Tags: json, spring-integration, spring-json

I use a `int:gateway`  to bring in a json String into a `int:channel`. When I print this json String using `<int-stream:stdout-channel-adapter/>` (or even if I print it inside a service activator attached to `int:channel`) it is printing key/value pairs with `=` instead of `:`
For example -> `GenericMessage [payload={id=1596096, key=SOME_KEY, address={first_name=John, last_name=......`
To solve this problem I have to use a `<int:object-to-json-transformer />`

What is the best way to work with raw JSON? My use case is to do a JSON to JSON transformation (also using a splitter).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your printed payload looks more like a `Map` or some POJO, so probably before that `<int-stream:stdout-channel-adapter/>` you have a step transforming an incoming string into that object.

For raw JSON we suggest to deal with a `#jsonpath()` SpEL-function: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/spel.html#built-in-spel-functions

Comment: In the splitter class I return List<String> using JsonPath.parse(json).read( "$.message[*]") and it is printed the list of json objects with : when I do a sys out in the splitter class.  However when I print the payload from the output channel of the splitter the json is printed with = instead of : as key value separator

Comment: Well, sounds like you need to share with us a minimal test-case to understand what us going on , reproduce and play with.